# Простая CMS для работы с базой данных

Tags: база-данных, cms

Подскажите есть ли какая-нибудь готовая CMS для работы с базой данных, в виде простой таблицы, типа Excel?

База данных достаточно большая, пополняется из готовых CSV, но работать с ней предстоит пользователям, для которых **phpMyAdmin** слишком сложный, да и редактировать только содержимое ячеек надо будет, без каких-либо дополнительных возможностей.

В идеале - CMS делает выборку по заданным параметрам и выводит таблицу с возможностью редактирования значений в полях авторизованным пользователям.

Comment: Ищу такое же решение, что нибудь нашли?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам целая CMS?? Напишите сами простое решение. Это будет намного быстрее и практичней, чем разбираться в куче ненужного вам в CMS. А для того чтобы вписывать данные в ячейки можно использовать виджет типа такого http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/editable/view/field.html или самому ajaxом отправлять на сервер данные.

Comment: Так в этом и стоит вопрос - есть ли готовое решение для поставленной задачи, чтобы не писать самим. Но даже если и писать самим, предложенный виджет, на мой взгляд, не особенно подходит. Нужно что-нибудь типа редактирования таблиц в google.docs.

Comment: Вы видимо не представляете что такое CMS и зачем она нужна. Если вам удобней Excel, то и заполняйте в нем, там тоже есть выборки и прочее. Зачем лишняя возня не пойму)

Comment: Всё просто: надо чтобы базу данных могли редактировать несколько неподготовленных зарегистрированных пользователей через веб-интерфейс.

Comment: @federk Именно для этих целей и создавались CMS, чтобы контент-менеджер мог без особых знаний БД редактировать данные.
Возможно вам просто нужно определиться с CMS исходя из ваших задач и потребностей.